# Custom table using multiple selects in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with multiple mission with a pick and drop information the time and the name.

I have this data:

| ID | PICK | DROP | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mission 1 | A | 1 | 12/11/2021-09:32 |
| Mission 2 | B | 1 | 12/11/2021-12:32 |
| Mission 3 | D | 2 | 12/11/2021-10:32 |
| Mission 4 | A | 5 | 12/11/2021-19:32 |

What I looking to do is to create a table to group by flow, in our example our flow are:

- Flow 1: all pick from A and D
- Flow 2: all pick from B and C

All of this grouped in 3 column using date. using our example it will look like this:

| Flow | Morning | PM | NIGHT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FLOW 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| FLOW 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Here is what I looking:

1st select: first row of associated pick A and B

```
select *
from table mission 
where pick = A or pick = D 
as the flow1 

select count(*)
from flow1 
where date.hour < 11:01 -- this information as to be stored on the column morning
```

Is there a way to get this result using SQL Server?

Thanks for your help .

Comment: Why A and D and how does "Flow 1" get associated with those rows/values? What logic determines that Flow 1 has 1 in AM column, 2 in Morning column, and 0 in Night column? For me, "AM" does mean "morning" (as opposed to afternoon or evening). What is your logic?

Comment: Can you explain the time classifications that result in Morning/AM/Night, and what relevance does the ID or DROP columns have regarding the example results?

Comment: I modify it it' morning / PM / Night, morning it means bedore 11am , PM between 11:01 and 10pm and night between 6am 10:01pm and 6am

Comment: That's an unusual time classification since PM typically indicates post-meridiem, after midday.

Comment: Also that doesn't work for your test data, your results show Flow1 has 2 for morning but you only have 1 qualifying row.

Comment: flow 1 is the name that I want to give to the association of the select A and D it's not existing on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following "sort of" gives your desired results - I'm not clear on your time classifications but you can amend these as appropriate.

Using `Apply` to calculate the intermediate required results (to save repeating conditions or requiring a sub-query/CTE):

```
select Flow, Sum(Morning) Morning, Sum(PM) PM, Sum(Night) Night, Count(*) Total
from t
cross apply (values (Iif(pick in ('A','D'),'Flow 1','Flow 2')))f(Flow)
cross apply (values ( Convert(time, [DATE] )))v(T)
cross apply (
    select
        case when T >='06:00:00' and T < '11:00:00' then 1 else 0 end Morning,
        case when T >='11:00:00' and T < '22:00:00' then 1 else 0 end PM,
        case when T >='22:00:00' and T < '06:00:00' then 1 else 0 end Night
)c
group by Flow
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=f9810d4f26d8c0b6d7dd04ba1a72e916)

Comment: Flow it's not existing this is the name that I want to give to the association A and B.

Comment: @SalahBelabed Yes I realise that, have you  tried the query? See a [working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=f9810d4f26d8c0b6d7dd04ba1a72e916)

Comment: nice it's working, just last thing maybe you can help when i'm trying to use more than 10 Iif statement I'm getting an error nested 10 level

Comment: So `iif` is just syntactic sugar for `case` and `case when else` has a nesting limit of 10; however you could still use `case when` without any `else criteria`, a `case` expression will return after the first matching case so you can just do `case when a then b when c then d ... end` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT CASE([PICK] = 'A' OR [PICK] = 'C', "FLOW 1", "FLOW 2") AS FLOW and then group by FLOW

Comment: This would be a better answer if you wrote out the select statement they need and included all the results they are looking for. As posted currently this is more like a comment than an answer.